# Python regex find text in bullets& numbering list

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find text in bullet& numbering using regex in python

for example

> InDesign Docs provides a series of articles about using bullets and numbering to create outlines, multi-level lists, figure captions, and numbered steps.
>
> 1. blah blah blah blah
> 2. blah2 blah2 blah2
> 3. blah3 blah3 blah3

I want to grab the text after numbering & bullet list

for example

> blah blah blah blah
>   blah2 blah2 blah2
>   blah3 blah3 blah3

This is the code I tried:

```
import re
n= re.compile('\d\.\s+(.*)')
test2= """ test my name is aaaaaa 1. blah blah blah 2. blah2 blah2 blah2 3. blah3 blah3 blah3 4. blah4 blah4 blah4"""
print n.search(test2).group(0)
```

Comment: import re

n= re.compile('\d\.\s+(.*)')
test2= """ test my name is aaaaaa
1. blah blah blah
2. blah2 blah2 blah2
3. blah3 blah3 blah3
4. blah4 blah4 blah4"""

print n.search(test2).group(0)

This is my code and the result only show 1. blah blah blah

Comment: Update the question instead; Python code in particular is useless in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dot doesn't match newline, unless you specify [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL); but then, you need to constrain the match to not just match all the text through the end of the document.

Also, you need to double the backslashes in your regex string, or use `r'...'` string syntax.

Maybe `r'(\d+\.\s.*\n?)+'` would work for your needs?